# select into oufile does not work

Tags: mysql, select, select-into, select-into-outfile

Why would the following query appear to run but I never can find the file outfile?

```
      select * 
      INTO OUTFILE 'outfile.csv'
      FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
      from nGrams
```

I have MySQL  5.5 and I am running my queries from MySQL Workbench

Comment: any errors? Can you post execution results after you run this query?

Comment: Sorry, I changed something and now I do not get an error. I just cannot find the file. I have tried specific directories and still I do not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file 'outfile.csv' will appear in the same directory as your database. On windows this is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySqlServerX.X\db_name